Django max_length validation for BinaryField causes KeyError in translation __init__.py
I have a simple model, something like
class Notenbild(models.Model):
    bild_data = models.BinaryField(max_length=500000, editable=True)

In admin.py
class BinaryFieldWithUpload(forms.FileField):
    def __init__(self, *, max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(max_length=max_length, allow_empty_file=allow_empty_file, **kwargs)

    def to_python(self, data):
        data = super().to_python(data)
        if data:
            image = Image.open(data)
            # some more processing with the image which I omitted here
            byte_array = io.BytesIO()
            image.save(byte_array, format='PNG')
            return byte_array.getvalue()
        return None

    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        attrs = super().widget_attrs(widget)
        if isinstance(widget, FileInput) and "accept" not in widget.attrs:
            attrs.setdefault("accept", "image/*")
        return attrs


@admin.register(Notenbild)
class NotenbildAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = [
        'bild_data',
        'vorschau',
    ]
    readonly_fields = ['vorschau']

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.BinaryField: {'form_class': BinaryFieldWithUpload},
    }

    @admin.display(description='Bild (Vorschau)')
    def vorschau(self, notenbild: Notenbild):
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(notenbild.bild_data).decode('utf-8')
        return format_html(
            f'<p>{len(notenbild.bild_data)} bytes</p>'
            f'<img src="data:image/png;base64,{encoded_image}" style="max-width:40rem; max-height:16rem" />'
        )

which works fine for saving images through the admin interface, which fit the size limits. However, when trying to save a file which exceeds the size limit, I get a very strange error:
KeyError at /admin/library/notenbild/368/change/
"Your dictionary lacks key 'max'. Please provide it, because it is required to determine whether string is singular or plural."

Django Version: 5.1.1
Exception Location: /Users/alex/Repositories/ekd-cms/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py, line 130, in _get_number_value

which the full stacktrace being

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 128, in _get_number_value
    return values[number]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

During handling of the above exception ('max'), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 92, in __call__
    panel.generate_stats(request, response)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py", line 201, in generate_stats
    template_data["context_list"] = self.process_context_list(
                                    
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/templates/panel.py", line 134, in process_context_list
    if key_values == context_layer:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 192, in __eq__
    return list(self) == other
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 192, in __eq__
    return list(self) == other
           ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen _collections_abc>", line 1026, in __iter__
    <source code not available>
                        ^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/forms/utils.py", line 197, in __getitem__
    return next(iter(error))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/core/exceptions.py", line 210, in __iter__
    message %= error.params
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 167, in __mod__
    return self.__cast() % other
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 148, in __mod__
    number_value = self._get_number_value(rhs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/alex/Repositories/my-project/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in _get_number_value
    raise KeyError(
    ^

which doesn't make any sense to me. The validation correctly caught the invalid data, but seems like this might be a bug on Django? Or am I using this thing incorrectly?
I've tried adding my own custom validator to the model:
from django.core.validators import BaseValidator
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

@deconstructible
class MaxFileSizeValidator(BaseValidator):
    message = _("Ensure the file is less than or equal to %(limit_value)s.")
    code = "limit_value"

    def __init__(self, limit_value, message=None):
        super().__init__(limit_value, message)
        self.limit_value = limit_value
        if message:
            self.message = message

    def __call__(self, value):
        cleaned = self.clean(value)
        limit_value = (
            self.limit_value() if callable(self.limit_value) else self.limit_value
        )
        params = {"limit_value": limit_value, "show_value": cleaned, "value": value}
        if self.compare(cleaned, limit_value):
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code=self.code, params=params)

    def compare(self, a, b):
        return len(a) > b

and
class Notenbild(models.Model):
    bild_data = models.BinaryField(max_length=500000, editable=True, validators=[MaxFileSizeValidator(500000)])


but whatever I try, the translation __init__.py method keep throwing this error, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Any ideas?

Please don't store binary data in the database.  Databases are not optimized for binary data, and will have to escape the data when talking to the Django application, making the amount of "bandwidth" between the database and the Django/Python layer quite large.

Can you also provide the full traceback?

I'm fully aware of the consequences and read through lot's of posts regarding the topic of storing binary data in the database. I accept the consequences - we're only storing a total of 1000 images which are 10k - 100k in size. This is not the problem that I have.
